# iOS local notifications showing in Simulator but not device

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Firebase listener that launches a notification when it fires like so:

```
chat.ref.child("lastMessage").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    let lastMessage = snapshot.value as! String
    chat.lastMessage = lastMessage
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    chat.lastMessageText = "New Message!"

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "You have a new Message!"
    content.subtitle = chat.title
    content.body = chat.lastMessage
    content.badge = 1

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger (timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Also have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in })
}
```

The problem I am having is, although the HomeScreen notifications are working in the simulator, they are not showing on the device. All permissions are granted on the device. Reading some questions here I found some answers that suggested I add the following in the app delegate:

```
application.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "showNotification", expirationHandler: nil)
```

but this actually disabled notifications on the simulator too. The notifications did work on the device before but stopped very suddenly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure push notifications are enabled in the capabilites tab of your project settings.

Comment: these are local notifications.